# Flutter SVG rendering

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried adding an image with a SVG source to my flutter application.

`new AssetImage("assets/images/candle.svg"))`

But I didn't get any visual feedback.
How can I render an SVG picture in Flutter?

Comment: try using simple to use ```flutter_svg 0.14.0 ``` package it works like charm more info here https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg ,all thanks to this guy https://github.com/dnfield who ported the chrome's svg rendering logic to dart

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Flutter does not currently support SVG. Follow [issue 1831](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1831) for updates.

If you absolutely need vector drawing you can see the [Flutter Logo widget](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/flutter_logo.dart) as an example of how to draw using the `Canvas` API, or rasterize your image on the native side and pass it to Flutter as a bitmap, but for now your best bet is probably to embed high-resolution rasterized asset images.

Comment: Also if you don't need color, you can always go the font route the way the Icons package does.

Comment: well after all he needs to simply render an svg image any svg library could do like this one https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

Comment: the issue is open since 13 Feb 2016. how long we need to wait?

Comment: @BloodLoss look at Dan Field's answer. User `flutter_svg` package

Comment: new SvgPicture.asset('asset_name.svg')

Answer (score 127):

Fonts are a great option for a lot of cases.

I've been working on a library to render SVGs on a canvas, available here:
https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg

The API as of right now would look something like

```
new SvgPicture.asset('asset_name.svg')
```

to render asset_name.svg (sized to its parent, e.g. a `SizedBox`).  You can also specify a `color` and `blendMode` for tinting the asset..

It's now available on pub and works with a minimum of Flutter version 0.3.6.  It handles a bunch of cases but not everything - see the GitHub repo for updates and to file issues.

The original GitHub issue referenced by Colin Jackson is really not meant to be primarily focused on SVG in Flutter.  I opened another issue here for that: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15501

Comment: A little off topic but does this have iOS support? As far as I know, iOS supports vectors in PDF format so I'm just curious if this can be used for rendering vectors on iOS as well

Comment: It should work on any platform Flutter supports.  It's all written in Dart using `Canvas` methods.

Comment: why doesnt it support latest flutter stable instead preview

Comment: Hi Dan, Can you also add support for - dart:svg library - https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-svg/dart-svg-library.html ? does flutter has dart2 support ?

I want to have multiple SVGElements all combined into one large serialized string and then use your library to render the SVG

Comment: dart:svg is used with HTML and dart2js. It's very different than this.

Comment: flutter_svg takes too long for some svgs why is that?

Comment: SVGs can use arbitrarily expensive things, either to parse or to draw or both.

Comment: Is there a reason why my SVG's are coming out black?

Answer (score 36):

Developers from the Flutter community created a lib to handle svg files. We can use it as

```
new SvgPicture.asset(
  'assets/images/candle.svg',
  height: 20.0,
  width: 20.0,
  allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
),
```

I found a small example of SVG [implementation here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2019/06/flutter-draw-svg-vector-drawables.html).

Comment: Just FYI - this is not an official/first party plugin.  That said, it should support a lot of common use cases.

Comment: Yes, and the thing that this plugin depends on other packages, its highly important to keep it updated by the authors.  I can't use this package as some other package conflicts with its old xml ^4.0.x dependency

Answer (score 27):

The work around for now is use fonts

https://icomoon.io/

```
  fonts:
   - family: icomoon
     fonts:
       - asset: assets/fonts/icomoon.ttf
```

Useage

```
  static const IconData TabBarHome= const IconData(0xe906, fontFamily: 'icomoon');
  static const IconData TabBarExplore= const IconData(0xe902, fontFamily: 'icomoon');
```

Replace the ### eg (906)

Comment: How can I use this? lets say I have an svg file in asset/svg/mysvg.svg 
I can't replace the hex with the path. 1st argument is an int.

Answer (score 15):

You can follow the below steps 
 - visit http://fluttericon.com 
 - upload your SVG icons 
 - click on download button
 - you will get two files 
 1. iconname.dart 
2. iconname.ttf font file 
- use this file in flutter & import iconname.dart

Comment: I used this method successfully. See my detailed answer here.

Comment: The flutterIcon is great but its not supported for 3 years since 2020. Github repository has 200.0 issues. Has anyone found similar project like that to generate ttf icons?

Answer (score 9):

step 1. add dependency in your pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
     flutter_svg: any
```

the Advantage of version any is you can use in any SDK version
but dependencies version is most important so add suitable version for your dependency.

step 2. **import** the flutter svg package in your app

```
 import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
```

step 3. just use like below

```
 SvgPicture.asset(
    'assets/images/bm-icon1.svg',
     width: 18.0,
     height: 18.0,
  ),
```

Comment: How is this answer different from @Robin's?

Comment: @OjonugwaJudeOchalifu This one came before Robin's, so this deserves the credit and the upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this library for rendering SVG Images - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

Example -

```
Container(
    child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/yourImage.svg")
)
```

Comment: this package is working fine as my requirements

Answer (score 5):

Of possible interest:  There's a newer Flutter SVG library called jovial_svg.  I wrote it to handle a more robust subset of SVG than what I was able to find on pub.dev at the time.  While I was at it, I also made a binary format that SVG assets can be compiled to.  It's a little more compact, and about 10x faster to read, so it's a good choice for assets you package with your application.

The library is at https://pub.dev/packages/jovial_svg

Comment: is it possible to render local (Asset) SVG images?,  f yes how ? i am not able to find exact solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes.  Indeed, the demo program does just this.  See `ScalableImage.fromSIAsset` if it's been compiled to a `si` file, or `ScalableImage.fromSvgAsset` if you want to bundle a (less effcient) SVG file directly.  If you're using `ScalableImageWidget`, there's `ScalableImageSource.fromSI` and `ScalableImageSource.fromSvg`.

Answer (score 5):

I solved similar problem by converting the svg images to ttf at fluttericon.com.

These are the steps involved.

Keep all your svg files in a folder.
Upload all of them to fluttericon by using the uploader there.
You can select all of them and drag and drop at the spot.
Give your icons a dart class name at the top: like, Svgicons

Select all your icons and press Download.

It will download a zip file with a dart file and fonts folder which contains Svgicons.ttf.

copy the fonts folder to your project folder and refer to it as an asset in pubspec.yaml.

```
fonts:
  - family: Svgicons
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/Svgicons.ttf
```

import the svgicons_icons.dart where you are going to use the images.
Sample:

```
import '../svgicons_icons.dart';

import 'social_media.dart';

class SocialMediaRepository {
  List<SocialMedia> getSocialMedia = [
    SocialMedia(id: 1, title: "Facebook", iconAsset:Svgicons.facebook, isFavorite: false),
    SocialMedia(id: 2, title: "Instagram", iconAsset: Svgicons.instagram, isFavorite: false),
    SocialMedia(id: 3, title: "LinkedIn", iconAsset: Svgicons.linkedin, isFavorite: false),
    ....
```

Here iconAsset is of type IconData which used to be a String referring to the svg image originally.

Display the ttf by using

```
    ...
    Icon(item.iconAsset),
    SizedBox(width: 10),
    Text(item.title),
  ],
),
```

where item is the object containing IconData.
Now you can remove the reference to svg images from the project.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**flutter support special type of svg**

**if have style tag then not load svg image in flutter**
**flutter support inline styling  in svg**

Comment: very usefull !! thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use flare to create animations and just import .flr as an asset

```
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new FlareActor("assets/Filip.flr", alignment:Alignment.center, fit:BoxFit.contain, animation:"idle");
  }
}
```

visit flare_flutter https://pub.dev/packages/flare_flutter

Answer (score 0):

Svg in flutter https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

1. add package in pubspec.yaml

   dependencies:
   flutter_svg: any

   assets:
   -assets/images/
2. to insert svg.

   SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/password-icon.svg',
   width: 24, height: 29.2),