# Using a SVG as a background image for a Container

Tags: dart, flutter

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087400/flutter-svg-rendering) I am using Flutter's SVG package (`flutter_svg`) to render a [SVG image](https://openclipart.org/download/310196/1542216179.svg).

I want to use the SVG as a `Container` background with `Text` in the middle.

[image: example of Container with background image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(image: SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/example.svg',
          ),),
      ),
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Welcome to my Flutter App',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1.copyWith(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          )
        ),
      ],
    )
```

The problem I am finding is that `SvgPicture` is not an `ImageProvider` so I can't add the `BoxDecoration` to get a background image.

Is there a way to then use `SvgPicture` as a Container's box decoration or background?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

how about using a stack() and build everything on top of that. That is how I have done it with just an image as a background for the full viewport.

Comment: how this can be achieved using a stack layout? cannot find the way to do as this post says.

Comment: Simple example would be more useful :)

Answer (score 41):

The exact way to use an SvgPicture is like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/images/splash/background.svg',
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ),
        Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[Expanded(child: _createLogo())],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [flutter_svg_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg_provider)

Like this :

```
import 'package:flutter_svg_provider/flutter_svg_provider.dart';

Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(image: Svg(
            'assets/example.svg',
          ),),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Doesn't work!! The argument type 'Svg' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'.

Comment: The latest version of flutter_svg_provider (0.1.9 as of now) does support this. This answer is correct.

Comment: well tested, it works in 2022

Comment: I have upvoted for this post because it work properly .

Comment: It's not working 2022, believe me. I tried and gave some kind of error like : 
"'Svg' isn't a function. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named 'Svg'."

Comment: @Davencode It's because you are using flutter_svg instead of flutter_svg_provider package

Comment: @ThiagoViana ok, I'll try it and I tell you if it works in this post. In any case I find out another solution.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
   import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: _getSvgImageProvider('assets/background.svg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
    );
  }

  ImageProvider _getSvgImageProvider(String assetName) {
    final svgString = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assetName);
    final DrawableRoot svgDrawableRoot = SvgParser.parse(svgString);
    final ui.Picture picture = svgDrawableRoot.toPicture();
    final ui.Image image = picture.toImage(
      svgDrawableRoot.viewport.viewBox.width.toInt(),
      svgDrawableRoot.viewport.viewBox.height.toInt(),
    );
    final provider = MemoryImage(
      Uint8List.view(image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png).buffer),
    );
    return provider;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you use presentation attributes instead of CSS when exporting/saving your SVG file. Otherwise it won't work.

Then use the 'flutter_svg_provider' package, double check that you are importing that package and not the 'flutter_svg' package, and finally create your SVG image like this: `Svg('path/to/your/file.svg')`.

Now you can use that image in your boxDecoration and it should work properly.