# svg image as button in flutter

Tags: svg, imagebutton, flutter-layout

I created a play-button and saved it as a svg dokument.

I have also created my home screen with a picture in the background and a floatingActionButton centered. (I used stack for this).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class MyBackgroundWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
                child: new Image.asset('assets/Backgr.png'),
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity),
            Center(
              child: new FloatingActionButton(
                  child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                  backgroundColor: new Color(0xFFE57373),
                   onPressed: () {}),
        ),

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

My question is: Can I use my svg-image as button instead of my current floatingActionButton? If yes, can I please get some help how to do this or where I should start looking for how to do this?

I still want my background picture and a centered button :)

Thank you!

Comment: I just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087400/flutter-svg-rendering

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `Gesture Detector` to add click functionality to any Widget in Flutter:

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    print("onTap called.");
  },
  child: Text("foo"),
),
```

And the child svg Widget is as simple as using this lib (since flutter still doesn't have native SVG support):
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

Answer (score 21):

If you want to create a clickable icon, surround your SVG (loaded using the package [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)) with an `IconButton` and you will
have an `onTap` method offered, like this:

```
child: IconButton(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
          'path to your asset',
        ),
        onPressed: null //do something,
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the InkWell to add click functionality to any Widget in Flutter:

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    print("onTap function."); 
  }, 
  child: Icon( 
     CstomIcon.custico, 
  ),
),
```

refer this post [Flutter SVG rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087400/flutter-svg-rendering/58425258#58425258) to add svg as icon and put SVG as child of InkWell

Comment: Any way we can add ink effect on top of the svg? I can only do that with other images types (png, jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete solution using the **[flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)** library. Wrap your widget with **InkWell** Widget.

```
InkWell( 
        onTap: () {
                    // todo : your code is here
                    print("back button clicked ");
                  },
                  child: getSVGImage("assets/images/arrow_back.svg"))
```

Here, is my helper method getSVGImage("YOUR_ASSET_PATH"). You can paste it to another file to use further access.

```
Widget getSVGImage(String assetName) {
  final Widget companyLogo = SvgPicture.asset(assetName);
  return companyLogo;
}
```

Add dependency like below for flutter_svg package:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
```