# ListView of image freezes when I load page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of images just two of them in a Card Widget inside a ContrainedBox widget. I want to add more. When I click and load the page the application freezes.

Here is my Widget

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DevScaffold(
      title: "Team",
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: teams.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
            elevation: 0.0,
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                      ),
                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        imageUrl: teams[index].image,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),...
```

Here is my data class:

```
List<Sponsor> sponsors = [
  Sponsor(
    name: "Google Developer Groups",
    image: "https://devfestflorida.org/images/logos/gdg-logo-new.svg",
    desc: "Platinum Sponsor",
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/community/gdg/',
  ),
  Sponsor(
    name: "Neoware Studios",
    image: "https://devfestflorida.org/images/logos/STUDIOSLOGO_WITHTM.png",
    desc: "Platinum Sponsor",
    url: 'https://www.neowarestudios.com/',
  ),
];...
```

There was no real exception thrown on the flutter side of things that made much sense, but here's the log:

```
C:\Users\javier.carrion\OneDrive\CodeVista\TechEvents\DevFest\DevFest2019Nov\devfestcenfl\devfestcenfl>flutter analyze
Analyzing devfestcenfl...
No issues found! (ran in 17.4s)

C:\Users\javier.carrion\OneDrive\CodeVista\TechEvents\DevFest\DevFest2019Nov\devfestcenfl\devfestcenfl>
C:\Users\javier.carrion\OneDrive\CodeVista\TechEvents\DevFest\DevFest2019Nov\devfestcenfl\devfestcenfl>
C:\Users\javier.carrion\OneDrive\CodeVista\TechEvents\DevFest\DevFest2019Nov\devfestcenfl\devfestcenfl>
C:\Users\javier.carrion\OneDrive\CodeVista\TechEvents\DevFest\DevFest2019Nov\devfestcenfl\devfestcenfl>
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1087], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.5 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 1aedbb1835 (13 days ago), 2019-10-17 08:37:27 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\javier.carrion\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin version 35.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.39.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.5.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: The svg is rendering? , i think CachedNetworkImage only renders images and that may be causing trouble https://devfestflorida.org/images/logos/gdg-logo-new.svg

Comment: No it is not rendering. You think I should change it to a .PNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments CachedNetworkImage does not render svg. Flutter does not support SVG, however you can use a package that provides support like [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg).

Here is a more information about [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44087571/5224387) support