# I can't use svg on flutter web how can i do it?

Tags: flutter

Hi i cant seem to get svg images to showup on flutter web
i saw two questions on stackoverflow with green tick to the answer that it says 
we can use Image.asset() as svg container but it doesn't work

what is the solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter SVG rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087400/flutter-svg-rendering)

Comment: Hi no it doesnt

Answer (score 4):

Until there is a [proper solution](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/173) you can use a [HtmlElementView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HtmlElementView-class.html) to show a svg on flutter web.

HtmlElementView can be used like this:

```
HtmlElementView(
    viewType: 'img-svg-${hashCode}',
)
```

You have to register your viewType first before you can use it:

```
platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('img-svg-${hashCode}',
      (int viewId) {
    final String base64 = base64Encode(utf8.encode(svgString));
    final String base64String = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,$base64';
    final html.ImageElement element = html.ImageElement(
        src: base64String, height: width.toInt(), width: width.toInt());
    return element;
});
```

I created an [example project](https://github.com/masewo/flutter_svg_web_example) that shows how to load svg from asset and how to do the web import dance if you want to use it for mobile and for web.