# How to put SVG icons in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, menu, drawer

Put this code in pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_svg: ^0.19.3
```

Even I put in assets these

```
assets:
     - assets\icons\logo.jpg
     - assets\icons\menuicon.svg
     - assets\icons\searchIcon.svg
```

In code it looks like this

```
IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.searchicon.svg),
                    onPressed: () {},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter SVG rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087400/flutter-svg-rendering)

Answer (score 15):

The Icon parameter accept any kind of widget not only Icon So you can use any widget like below

```
   IconButton(icon: SvgPicture.asset(
      assetName,
      color: Colors.red,
      semanticsLabel: 'Label'
    ),onPressed: () {},
```

Comment: The problem is we have to manually control theming on each icon. It does not inherit IconTheme class.

Comment: @HamdamMuqimov how about passing ````Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color```` for the color property?