# How can I load an SVG asset in a Flutter package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing an UI components library and I want to use some SVG icons, I added them to the package's `pubspec.yaml` like this :

```dart
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/svg/
```

And I tried to load the SVG file like this, to no avail:

```dart
 const String backArrow = 'assets/svg/back_arrow.svg';
```

I got an exception:

```
FlutterError (Unable to load asset: assets/svg/back_arrow.svg)
```

How can I properly load those assets in my package?

Comment: Specifically this answers to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67948393/5882307

Comment: close your IDE..then open and try running your app

Answer (score 0):

Try this package from pub.dev: [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)